# Is there a generic method of accessing DOM elements without an id through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a `<p>` tag without an `id` attribute that I'd like to remove. Would I be able to use a generic DOM string to access this element?

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <div>
            <p> // yada yada 
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my instance I'm trying to remove the paragraph element with jQuery by:

```
$(function () {
    var remove = $(" /*Generic label goes here */ ").remove();
});
```

I thought it would be `document.body.div.firstChild` Is something like this possible?

Comment: Yes, there are tons of DOM traversal methods. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference and http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: did you even try to find a solution?!?! Googling `JavaScript firstChild` returns a bunch of results that answer this question and sets you on your way!

Comment: That's exactly what I did but I didn't get very far. I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use normal css selectors within jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var remove = $("body div p:first-child").remove();
});
```

If you just want top level divs inside body, use `body > div p:first-child`. if you only want p elements which are direct childs of body, use `body > div > p:first-child`.

Depending on what you need, you can also get all p elements and then iterate over them!

Comment: Oh that's right I'm supposed to use CSS selectors. I sincerely appreciate the help.